# select item on template dom-repeat to animate with neon-animated-pages

Tags: polymer-1.0

I will try to be simple, i'm on the final stage of my app (a portfolio page), and i only need the interaction between pages, so:

#### short question:

how to select an specific item of some custom-element made with template is="dom-repeat" and publish like a property to bind later outside with another element attribute (selected="{{}}")

---

#### long question:

Form top to bottom. I've got a custom element with two elements inside of neon-animated-pages. The first element is a grid of cards made whit template is="dom-repeat", and the second is another neon animated pages, inside of this are all the works-pages (all pages make a change in a declarative way like this [demo](http://morethanreal.github.io/neon-animation-demo/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/declarative/index.html))

portfolio-page template:

```
<neon-animated-pages id="page" class="flex" selected="{{projectSelected}}">

 <portfolio-grid id="grid" on-tap="_goToProject" card-selected="{{selected}}"> <-- card-selected not defined yet -->
 </portfolio-grid>

 <work-pages work-selected="{{selected}}" on-back-portfolio="_backPortfolio">
 </work-pages>

</neon-animated-pages>
```

portfolio-page script:

```
Polymer({
  is: "portfolio-page",

  properties:{
   projectSelected:{
    type: Number,
    value: 0
   }
  },

  _goToProject: function(){
   this.projectSelected = 1;
  },

  _backPortfolio: function(){
   this.projectSelected = 0;
  }
});
```

Inside of portfolio grid, is another custom element, a simple card with attributes like title and description, the img attribute here is the css id inside of the portfolio-card which sets the background image of my card:

```
<dom-module id="portfolio-grid">
<template>
  <style>
    SOME STYLE HERE
  </style>

  <div class="layout horizontal wrap">

    <template is="dom-repeat" id="cardList" items="[[cards]]">

    <portfolio-card class$="{{item.class}}" img="{{item.img}}"
      title="{{item.title}}" description="{{item.description}}">
    </portfolio-card>

    </template>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  Polymer({

    is: "portfolio-grid",

    behaviors: [
      Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior
    ],

    properties: {
      cards: {
        type: Array,
        value: function(){
          return [
            { img: 'monalisa', title: 'The Mona Lisa', 
            description: 'Painting', class: 'cardSmall'},
            { img: 'starrynight', title: 'Starry Night', 
            description: 'Painting', class: 'cardSmall'},
            { img: 'david', title: 'David', 
            description: 'Sculpture', class: 'cardMedium'},
            { img: 'memory', title: 'The Persistence Of Memory', 
            description: 'Painting', class: 'cardSmall'},
            { img: 'venus', title: 'Venus de milo', 
            description: 'Sculpture', class: 'cardSmall'},
            { img: 'birth', title: 'Birth of Venus', 
            description: 'Painting', class: 'cardMedium'},
            { img: 'guernica', title: 'The Guernica', 
            description: 'Painting', class: 'cardBig'},
            { img: 'nightwatch', title: 'The Night Watch', 
            description: 'Painting', class: 'cardSmall'},
            { img: 'kiss', title: 'The Kiss', 
            description: 'Painting', class: 'cardSmall'}
          ]
        }
      },

      animationConfig: {
        value: function() {
          return {
            'entry': {
              name: 'fade-in-animation',
              node: this,
              timing: 2000
              },
            'exit': {
              name: 'fade-out-animation',
              node: this
              }
            }
          }
        }
       }
  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

And finally my work-pages, here i've got all the works i want to show with fixed navigation controls, all working good (next, previous and back to portfolio grid):

```
<dom-module id="work-pages">
<template>
  <style>
  SOME STYLE HERE
  </style>

  <section id="container" class="layout vertical">
    <neon-animated-pages id="works" class="flex" attr-for-selected="work" selected="{{workSelected}}">

      <workpage-monalisa work="monalisa"></workpage-monalisa>
      <workpage-starrynight work="starrynight"></workpage-starrynight>
      <workpage-david work="david"></workpage-david>
      <workpage-memory work="memory"></workpage-memory>
      <workpage-venus work="venus"></workpage-venus>
      <workpage-birth work="birth"></workpage-birth>
      <workpage-guernica work="guernica"></workpage-guernica>
      <workpage-nightwatch work=nightwatch""></workpage-nightwatch>
      <workpage-kiss work="kiss"></workpage-kiss>

    </neon-animated-pages>
  </section>

  <!-- Navigation Buttons -->
  <div class="controls">
    <!-- Back Work Button -->
    <iron-icon id="menuIcon" icon="mrcauko-icons:menu"></iron-icon>
    <!-- Back Work Button -->
    <div id="back">
      <iron-icon class="button" icon="mrcauko-icons:back" on-tap="_goPrev"></iron-icon>
    </div>
    <!-- Next Work Button -->
    <div id="next">
      <iron-icon class="button" icon="mrcauko-icons:next" on-tap="_goNext"></iron-icon>
    </div>
      <!-- Bottom Bar -->
    <div class="bottomBar layout horizontal">
      <div class="flex"></div>
      <iron-icon id="backToPortfolio" icon="mrcauko-icons:view-portfolio" on-tap="_goBackPortfolio"></iron-icon>
      <div class="flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  Polymer({

    is: "work-pages",

    behaviors: [
      Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior
    ],

    properties: {
      workSelected: {
        type: String,
        notify: true
      },
      animationConfig: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
          return {
            'entry': {
              name: 'fade-in-animation',
              node: this
            },
            'exit': {
              name: 'fade-out-animation',
              node: this
              }
            }
          }
        }
    },

    listeners: {
      'neon-animation-finish': '_onNeonAnimationFinish'
    },

    _onNeonAnimationFinish: function(){       //This isn't working
      this.$.works.scroller.scrollTop = 0;
    },

    _goBackPortfolio: function(){
      this.fire('back-portfolio');
    },

    _goPrev: function() {
      this.$.works.selectPrevious();
    },

    _goNext: function() {
      this.$.works.selectNext();
    }

  });
</script>
```

I've been thinking different aproaches but don't know how to implement them.

1. Because i've got the same name in item.img and attr-for-selected="work" in the work-pages, somehow say "hey, when i click this card, the item.work is the same as the work-selected"(see portfolio-page)
2. Don't know if i need to use the [array selector](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#array-selector)
3. Wrap the portfolio-grid inside an iron-selector element, to establish attr-for-selected$="{{item.img}}"(not tried yet but i think this way is using too many elements, and im sure there is a better way)

I know there is demos with neon-animated-pages, but my project is more specific, besides the code of the demos is too complicated for my poor knowledge of js (that's why i love polymer, 'cause i can create great things, and i'm not an expertise in js). I'm not asking to do my job, just only some enlightening to continue. So I ask for help from the immortals like you guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need your data to flow from <portfolio-grid> to <work-pages>, then I think the array selector is the way to go.

It should be fairly simple to implement, just like the example in the documentation (see the link your provided).

Comment: well, it's not only that, first i was trying to figure how to bind the card with the corresponding workpage, but actually i will make hero transitions between the card and the works, this mean i need first to find the target and then animate the shared transitions, but i've not been able to implement the fisrt binding. In simple words i like to do the grid to fullscreen [demo]
[demo]: http://morethanreal.github.io/neon-animation-demo/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/grid/index.html

Comment: Hum, why are you using 2 instances of neon-animated-pages then? I think you only need one. The pages will be your <portfolio-grid> and all your <workpage-*> elements. Then your setup will be pretty similar to this demo http://morethanreal.github.io/neon-animation-demo/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/grid/index.html. As for your navigation buttons, they could be siblings of your neon-animated-pages, hidden when the displayed element is <portfolio-grid>.

Comment: ok, i did what you suggest, i put all the elements inside of one neo-animated-pages, but i still can't figure how to make the transition when i click the specific card to the specific work, any suggestion or example to use?.

Comment: Now i suppose you should listen to clicks on cards in <portfolio-grid> (here is [how](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#handling-events)) and fire an event. Then add a handler for this event in the parent element (still <portfolio-page> I suppose) and select the good page. That should do it. Otherwise, can you provide more snippets of your current code and provide more information about your current problem?

Comment: i did this http://jsbin.com/cemifu/edit?html,output, here i put all the elements inside of one neon-animated-pages (portfolio-grid, and all the projects-pages), the problem is that i don't know how to write the events and the handlers, hope this clears my question (please be nice, it's my first jsbin).
Also, i think i'm gonna to open another question to be more specific on the problem that i've got, and what i need. i will notify you about this.
Thank's for the support, meanwhile take a look my jsbin

Comment: Well, i think you should have been able to figure it out with the [documentation link](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#handling-events) i provided in my previous comment. Anyhow, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rpuxxcu/2/) (it does not run, that's expected) where i completed both **_selectCard** and **_showProject** methods, and added an "id" property for each card in the "cards" array to resolve the related page. Can you test that ?